# Which JavaScript version is used in Mozilla Firefox 56.0b9 (64-bit)?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was trying to find which version of Javascript is used in different  browsers. I got a url which will give the information on that.

https://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/systeminfo.cgi

When I open this url in Chrome(Version 60.0.3112.113) it was showing Javascript version `1.8`, which I think is correct. But when I open in Mozilla Firefox(56.0b9 (64-bit)) it is showing Javascript version `1.5`. But in Mozilla docs they says Javascript `1.8.5` is shipped with Mozilla Firefox 4. Is there anything I am missing? or is it showing correct? Is there any other method to find the Javascript versions in browsers?

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I am using Mozilla developer version(beta). I tried in 55.0.3 also. Both showing 1.5

Comment: Nobody actually talks about [javascript version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history) since Firefox4 (in 2010). So your question and this panel in the link doesn't mean much. There is of course [ECMAScript versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions), but you can't either say which is used by which browser, you would rather say which features are implemented in which version.